# How to analyse stops place of articulation?

Tags: phonetics, stops

Works which focus on differences in place of articulation of stops (like Sundara 2005, 2006) usually use spectral measurements (COG, skewness, SD, kurtosis) and relative burst intensity. It is not clear, however, in which interval do the compute these measurements: many of them divide the burst from the VOT (like Sundara 2005, 2006), whereas others do not declare this. So, it happens that in some works scholars talk about 'relative burst intensity', but it seems that their measurement is somehow taken at the middle of the VOT. I think that this could derive from Harrington's (1999) definition, in which he says that "the duration of the burst is also known as voice onset time, which is the principal acoustic parameter for  distinguishing be tween voiced stops and their voiceless counterparts in syllable-initial position in  English". 
Now, if I compute my measurements taking ALL the VOT interval, is it not too much / too late for investigating stops place of articulation? Is it possible that, in declaring this, they intend to move the cursor just after the boundary and assuming that they are computing burst measurements?